# pcl::PCLPointCloud2 usage

Tags: c++, point-cloud-library

I'm confused with when to use `pcl::PointCloud2` vs `pcl::PointCloudPointCloud`

For example, using these definitions for `pcl1_ptrA`, `pcl1_ptrB` and `pcl1_ptrC`:

```
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr pcl1_ptrA(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>); //pointer for color version of pointcloud
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr pcl1_ptrB(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>); //ptr to hold filtered Kinect image
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr pcl1_ptrC(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>); //ptr to hold filtered Kinect image
```

I can invoke the following PCL functions:

```
pcl::VoxelGrid<pcl::PointXYZRGB> vox;

vox.setInputCloud(pcl1_ptrA); 

vox.setLeafSize(0.02f, 0.02f, 0.02f);

vox.filter(*pcl1_ptrB); 

cout<<"done voxel filtering"<<endl;

cout<<"num bytes in original cloud data = "<<pcl1_ptrA->points.size()<<endl;

cout<<"num bytes in filtered cloud data = "<<pcl1_ptrB->points.size()<<endl; // ->data.size()<<endl; 

Eigen::Vector4f xyz_centroid; 

pcl::compute3DCentroid (*pcl1_ptrB, xyz_centroid);

float curvature;

Eigen::Vector4f plane_parameters;  

pcl::computePointNormal(*pcl1_ptrB, plane_parameters, curvature); //pcl fnc to compute plane fit to point cloud

Eigen::Affine3f A(Eigen::Affine3f::Identity());

pcl::transformPointCloud(*pcl1_ptrB, *pcl1_ptrC, A);
```

However, if I instead use `pcl::PCLPointCloud2` objects, e.g.:

```
pcl::PCLPointCloud2::Ptr pcl2_ptrA (new pcl::PCLPointCloud2 ());

pcl::PCLPointCloud2::Ptr pcl2_ptrB (new pcl::PCLPointCloud2 ());

pcl::PCLPointCloud2::Ptr pcl2_ptrC (new pcl::PCLPointCloud2 ());
```

This function  works:

```
pcl::VoxelGrid<pcl::PCLPointCloud2> vox;

vox.setInputCloud(pcl2_ptrA); 

vox.setLeafSize(0.02f, 0.02f, 0.02f);

vox.filter(*pcl2_ptrB);
```

But these do not even compile:

```
//the next 3 functions do NOT compile:

Eigen::Vector4f xyz_centroid; 

pcl::compute3DCentroid (*pcl2_ptrB, xyz_centroid);

float curvature;

Eigen::Vector4f plane_parameters;   

pcl::computePointNormal(*pcl2_ptrB, plane_parameters, curvature); 

Eigen::Affine3f A(Eigen::Affine3f::Identity());

pcl::transformPointCloud(*pcl2_ptrB, *pcl2_ptrC, A);
```

I am having trouble discovering which functions accept which objects.  Ideally, wouldn't all PCL functions accept `pcl::PCLPointCloud2` arguments?

Answer (score 5):

`pcl::PCLPointCloud2` is a ROS (Robot Operating System) message type replacing the old `sensors_msgs::PointCloud2`. Hence, it should only be used when interacting with ROS. (see an example [here](http://wiki.ros.org/pcl/Tutorials/hydro?action=AttachFile&do=view&target=example_voxelgrid_pcl_types.cpp))

If needed, PCL provides two functions to convert from one type to the other:

```
void fromPCLPointCloud2 (const pcl::PCLPointCloud2& msg, cl::PointCloud<PointT>& cloud);
void toPCLPointCloud2 (const pcl::PointCloud<PointT>& cloud, pcl::PCLPointCloud2& msg);
```

**Extra Information**

`fromPCLPointCloud2` and `toPCLPointCloud2` are PCL library functions for conversions. ROS has wrappers for those functions in [pcl_conversions/pcl_conversions.h](http://docs.ros.org/hydro/api/pcl_conversions/html/namespacepcl.html) that you should use instead. These will call the right combinations of functions to convert between the message and templated format.

Answer (score 3):

**As a follow-up for what Albert said,** `For ROS Hydro and later (if you are using ROS)`, PCL has done a work to remove all its dependencies from ROS.  What this means is the pcl has created a set of classes which are almost identical to the corresponding ROS messages, in order to minimize API breakage for pcl users. PointCloud users using `"now depracated" sensor_msgs::PointCloud2` are now asked to use `pcl_conversions` package, this package implements conversions `from/to sensor_msgs::PointCloud2 to/from) pcl::PointCloud` and should include :

```
#include <pcl_conversions/pcl_conversions.h>
```

and the ROS code should be modified as the following :

```
void foo(const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2 &pc)
{
  pcl::PCLPointCloud2 pcl_pc;
  pcl_conversions::toPCL(pc, pcl_pc);
  pcl::SomePCLFunction(pcl_pc);
  ...
}
```

Also, pcl is no longer packaged by the ROS community as a catkin package, so any packages which directly depend on pcl should instead use the new rosdep rules libpcl-all and libpcl-all-dev and follow the PCL developer's guidelines for using PCL in your CMake. Generally this means that a package.xml will change like this:

```
find_package(PCL REQUIRED)
...
include_directories(${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
...
target_link_libraries(<YOUR_TARGET> ${PCL_LIBRARIES})
```

More on the migration rules can be found [here](http://wiki.ros.org/hydro/Migration), [here](https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/wiki/Remove-ROS) and [here](https://github.com/ros-perception/pcl_conversions).